# Select option ajax inside modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have problem with my modal, I have modal and inside my modal I have selecoption factory which my select using ajax jQuery like this

```
$('#fFactory').change(function(e) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: host + "budget/FFactory",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
      console.log($("#fFactory").html(data));
    }
  });
});
```

But my problem is, my select option wont work inside modal. How do I trigger my select option inside modal??

My html :

```
<?php
    $json = array();

    if($data['title']=='additem')
    {
        $json['title'] = 'Add Item';
    }
    else
    {
        $json['title'] = 'Add Item';
    }

    $json['body'] = '<div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">
                                    Factory
                                </label>
                                <select id="fFactory" class="form-control input-sm">
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="exampleInputPassword1">
                                    Password
                                </label>
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>';       
    $json['footer'] = '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-o modal-close pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">
                        close
                    </button>';


    // var_dump($json);
    echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

I'm using json. On jQuery when active modal

```
$('#addbudget').click(function(){
            var code = "";
            var modal = $('.bs-modal-lg');
            var modalData = jQuery.parseJSON(ajaxPOST(code,'budget/form/additem',null,true));
            modal.find('.modal-title').html(modalData.title);
            modal.find('.modal-body').html(modalData.body);
            modal.find('.modal-footer').html(modalData.footer);

            modal.modal('show');
        });
```

UPDATE :

How silly I am, I was wrong on json, I forgot have to add function init: on jQuery now it works. I'm so sorry about silly I am. Thanks for all who helping me again :)

Comment: use event delegation for dynamically added element. use `.on()`

Comment: @guradio : how to triggrer it? I know if click even, but how 'change' event?? Sorry, i'm kinda newbie on javascript

Comment: @Wolfzmus Is your id of `select` and $() selector same?

Comment: @HarikrishnanN yes, i need to triggrer my select with ajax, is that worng?? If wrong pls tell me how to trigger my select with ajax inside modal.

Comment: Can you show your html code

Comment: @HarikrishnanN, i add code html, So you can see my question. I'm using json & jquery to showing my modal.

Comment: use `$(document).on('change','#fFactory',function(e) {` instead of `$('#fFactory').change(function(e) {`

Comment: @guradio ok i'm gonna try.

Comment: @guradio is not working still blank :(

Comment: @Wolfzmus pls update your code after you implement the deleagtion

Comment: @Wolfzmus Sorry, but your recent edit was not really acceptable. Please take a moment to read the Help Center article [Why can people edit my posts? How does editing work?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing). If you strongly disagree with any edit, use the flag option, under your question's tags, to ask for moderator intervention.

Comment: @TiesonT. these question was 1 years ago.....

Comment: @Wolfzmus _When_ the question was asked isn't really relevant to when it can be edited, but edits like `EDIT : Who ever edit my question you are blind!! I just finish my question and i just have the answer so stop edit my question, is wasting your time to edit. Geez... #rolleyes` are never acceptable. You can always ask to have your question locked or disassociated from your account if you don't want to receive further notifications.

Comment: @TiesonT. I can do that?? wow i never know. How?? Please explain me xD

Comment: Follow this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96732/how-do-i-remove-my-name-from-a-post-in-accordance-with-cc-by-sa-3-0